# Spring MVC opening PDF not working

Tags: spring-mvc

Trying to open a PDF in Chrome as suggested in another answer here. However, I'm getting the binary representation instead (see image). Content-disposition=attachment works, but inline doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Result:

[image]

Javaconfig (I think this is enabled by default but adding or removing this code doesn't make a difference):

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    ...

    @Bean
    public ResourceHttpMessageConverter httpConverter() {
        return new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(httpConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/man", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource manual(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=manual.pdf");
    return new FileSystemResource(servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/manual.pdf"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `produces`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/man", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
```